# determine if an array element contains an image

Tags: objective-c

Hi
If you have an array that stores images and text then displays the content in a random manner how can you check to know that the element about to be retrieved contains an image or text so that if an image I display a UIMageView and if text I display a UILabel

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your text is always an instance of NSString and your images are always instances of UIImage:

```
for (id obj in mixedArray) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
         // display via UILabel
    else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
         // display via UIImageView
}
```